# How to assign a variable within a pipe

Tags: bash, shell-script, pipe, environment-variables

I'm building a one liner in bash.
If making a script or writing temp files were an option, I wouldn't need to ask.

I need to assign a variable in the middle of a set of pipes to use down the line.

```
    cat list | awk '{print $1".modifications_to_name"' | (capture $NAME and pass $NAME down pipe) \
    | checkStatus | grep pertinentinfo | cleanupFormatOfPertinentInfo | sendAlert $NAME
```

Comment: Is there output from the `awk` that is not part of `$NAME` or how would you distinguish which parts should he `NAME` and which are only to be handled by `checkStatus`?  Perhaps some sample input and desired output would help clarify what you want

Comment: Why do you need to use pipes? You can use `;` to break up lines as though you ere writing a script. Thus it is still one line. something like:

``NAME=`cat list | awk '{print $1".modifications_to_name"}'`; echo $NAME | checkStatus | grep pertinentinfo | cleanupFormatOfPertinentInfo | sendAlert``

Comment: Eric,  the $NAME should always be the modified version..  the original list can be discarded.
............................
Kip,  I don't need pipes, just learning to "Embrace the single line".The backticks cause the line delimited list to become space delimited, which checkStatus will choke on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disregarding that your awk is missing a brace, and assuming list contains a single line, why not: `NAME=$( cat list | awk '{print $1".modifications_to_name"') && checkStatus | grep pertinentinfo | cleanupFormatOfPertinentInfo | sendAlert $NAME`

If you want to iterate through a list with multiple lines and have name evaluate to something different each time:

`while read NAME; do checkStatus | grep pertinentinfo | cleanupFormatOfPertinentInfo | sendAlert $NAME ; done < <(cat list | awk '{print $1".modifications_to_name"')`

This seems like an [X Y](http://xyproblem.info/) question though.

Comment: Thank You.


It was a total X_Y question.  Because I had good ways to avoid the problem, I wanted to expand my skillset.  And I didn't want a bunch of noisy answers.


The second part of your answer handles what I need elegantly.


I was/am hoping that someone would explain that there is a command/trick like tee for variables, rather than tee for files.